# Pyodbc executemany only returns last element inserted

Tags: python, database, insert, pyodbc

Using the following function:

```
import pyodbc

def execute_side_effect_stmt(sql_stmt: str, params: list):
    with get_connection() as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(sql_stmt, params)
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        response = []
        for row in results:
            response.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        conn.commit()
        if not response:
            return ''
        return response
```

With the following arguments:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO dbo.events
      (sha, duration)
      OUTPUT Inserted.id, Inserted.sha
      VALUES (?, ?)"""

params = [('123',1),('456', 2), ('789', 3)]

result = execute_side_effect_stmt(sql, params)
```

Result only returns the ***id*** and ***sha*** of the last entry in params. Everything is inserted correctly into the database. Any insights on why only the last insert gives an output would be very welcome.

Comment: related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `cursor.executemany()` executes the SQL statement for each element in `params`.
As shown in the [docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanyfalse-the-default), unless you set `cursor.fast_executemany = True`, the `INSERT` statement will be called `len(params)` times.

With `cursor.fast_executemany = True`, the result will be a single insert as described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanytrue)

As described:

> Here, all the parameters are sent to the database server in one bundle (along with the SQL statement), and the database executes the SQL against all the parameters as one database transaction. Hence, this form of `executemany()` should be much faster than the default `executemany()`. However, there are limitations to it, see [`fast_executemany`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany) for more details.

Your code could be modified to:

```py
import pyodbc

def execute_side_effect_stmt(sql_stmt: str, params: list):
    with get_connection() as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.fast_executemany = True
        cursor.executemany(sql_stmt, params)
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        response = []
        for row in results:
            response.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        conn.commit()
        if not response:
            return ''
        return response
```